# « Fool » en français ?

Tags: traduction, anglais, vocabulaire

Voici une phrase en anglais que je cherche à traduire :

> Any fool can write code that a computer can understand.

La traduction du mot *fool* me pose problème : j'ai pensé dans un premier temps à *imbécile*, mais j'ai l'impression que *imbécile* amène une notion péjorative que *fool* n'a pas.

Je perçois dans le mot *fool* une notion de naïveté (mais peut-être me trompé-je) que je n'arrive pas à traduire correctement.

Auriez-vous un mot à me suggérer ?

Comment: *Any* est ici aussi important que *fool*  et juste dire *n'importe qui est capable de...*  n'enlève rien, ou pas grand chose au sens de la phrase anglaise.
Sinon *fool* dans ce contexte est péjoratif et *imbécile*, *idiot*, *simple d'esprit*, me semble des traductions possibles.

Comment: Mais à ton avis, _N'importe qui est capable d'écrire du code..._ est-il plus proche du sens original que _N'importe quel imbécile est capable d'écrire du code..._ ?

Comment: @Laure: +1, et j'en aurais fait une réponse. Jacques: j'aurais traduit par *N'importe qui*, qui est suffisamment désinvolte et il me semble plus proche de l'original.

Comment: Pourquoi pas *abruti* ?

Comment: Cretin càest une possibilité :) Par contre l'affiramtion c'est pas vrai du tout, car il faut suivre au moin des regles formelles pour ecrire du code que un ordinateur peut comprendre.

Comment: Et tout à chacun trouve midi à sa porte.

Answer (score 10):

Je tiens, comme Laure, que *fool* est ici péjoratif, mais à mon sens moins agressif que le français *imbécile*. À moins que la traduction ne soit dans un registre très formel, je proposerais bien ***n'importe quel [quidam](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/quidam)*** ou ***n'importe quel [péquin](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/p%C3%A9quin)***.

Comment: Je ne connaissais pas l'orthographe `péquin`, par ailleurs inconnue dans le dictionnaire de l'Académie ni dans le TLFi.

Comment: @M42: j'avais spontanément écrit « pékin », puis j'ai vérifié dans le TLFi (qui n'a ni l'un ni l'autre), puis dans le wiktionaire, qui indique les deux orthographes mais qui donne une étymologie (le provençal) qui serait plus en accord avec l'orthographe que j'ai choisie au final…

Comment: On trouve bien [`pékin` dans le TFLi](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/pékin) 2e entrée.

Comment: @M42: ah oui, je suis passé à côté sans voir l'onglet de la deuxième entrée… merci !

Comment: Par contre, je confirme que dans le Sud-Est, on utilise bien *péquin*. Alors l'Académie française, ce qu'on en pense nous, pauvres péquins de province... ;)

Comment: Le Robert indique que **Pékin** origine de la variante *Péquin* aurait pour racine Pekk, "petit" (1797) avec sa variante provençale *péquin* "malingre". Pour les militaires c'est péjoratif d'être habillé en "pékin" (civil), synonyme : *mec*, **type** ce dernier pourrait répondre au contexte informatique sans connotation négative.

Answer (score 7):

Dans ce cas précis je dirais *le premier venu*. Si tu veux donner plus de précisions ça peut être *le premier **étudiant** venu*, *le premier **ingénieur** venu*, *le premier **crétin** venu*…

Answer (score 3):

Entendu (il y a longtemps) dans une équipe de développement.

> **Cromagnon enfant** peut coder pour un ordinateur

Les antiennes originales non expurgées :

- affirmative : "Cromagnon enfant sait faire ça",
- interrogative : "C'est Cromagnon enfant qu'à pissé ces lignes?"

Maintenant je dirais plutôt

> N'importe quel **ahuri** peut coder pour un ordinateur.

*Ajout :*

**Type** est anonyme, ni valorisant, ni péjoratif : on peut être *brave type* ou *pauvre type*, (ou les deux à la fois), cela dépend donc de l'adjectif ou du complément, et on trouve des tas de types qui font de l'informatique même pour s'exclamer, à contrario de la question *Ce type est un génie*.
Si *This guy's a genius fool* est possible, *type* est le plus universel.

Comment: `ahuri` c'est très approprié!

Answer (score 2):

"N'importe qui" peut être compris comme une forme péjorative de "Tout le monde".

Pas besoin d'ajouter "imbécile", il y a pour moi dans ce "fool" un côté méprisant, différent du "I made a fool of myself" plus naïf.

Answer (score 2):

Habituellement je traduis "fool" par "crétin" qui est un poil moins péjoratif que "imbécile", mais dans le contexte j'utiliserais plus "béotien" / "quidam" ou plus simplement "n'importe qui"

Comment: +1 pour *béotien*.

Comment: De mon point de vue, `crétin` est beaucoup plus péjoratif! Mal approprié dans ce cas.

Answer (score 1):

Je dirait à mi-chemin entre *idiot* et *bouffon*. Dans les années 90, on disait *teubé*, le verlan de *bête*.

Answer (score 1):

Dans ce contexte, le mot *fool* n'est pas péjoratif.  *N'importe qui* est la meilleure traduction.  *Any fool* est ici égal à *Anyone*.

Answer (score 0):

« N'importe quel **pécore**… »

Je trouve que dans ton exemple ça correspond impeccablement.

Comment: Ca ne serait pas un régionalisme par contre ?

Comment: https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/p%C3%A9core effectivement, non, c'est juste vieilli :)

Comment: @jv42 à choisir une source autant en prendre [une pertinente](http://dvlf.uchicago.edu/mot/p%C3%A9core).

Comment: Dictionnaire de 1935, c'est récent ! :p

Answer (score -2):

Pour le dire autrement, même un imbécile peut écrire du code qui peut être compris par un ordi. C'est-à-dire que les ordis ne comprennent pas vraiment des idées complexes de la même manière que nous comprenons. Ils ne comprend que des instructions simples, que n'importe qui peut écrire, même un imbécile.

Comment: Mais la réponse à la question ?

Answer (score -2):

I could suggest débile for a «fool».

Comment: *Débile* is a lot more pejorative than *fool*, more so than *imbécile* that was also proposed in this thread. It's downright insulting, even, to the level of *cretin* or *moron* in English.